# Python output to Kali terminal

Tags: python, linux

I have trouble to pipe the output of a command to other command.
For example I have a long list which I will iterate and each line I want to pipe it to next command, but I am receving "FileNotFoundError:". I change a little bit of the real commands, but the logic is the same. I tried different options, but the result is the same. Any hints?

```
import subprocess

txt = "Hello, it is good sunny Day"
res = subprocess.Popen(["echo", txt], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
res_dec = res.decode('utf-8')
res1 = subprocess.Popen([res_dec.strip(), "| grep good"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print(res1.decode('utf-8'))
```

And the error is:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Hello, it is good sunny Day'

Comment: Why using python to launch shell commands ?

Comment: I have another big script which is based on python.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `subprocess.run()` like the documentation recommends?

Comment: This is because this is not how you pipe output, the `|` stands for: Take whatever the command on the left side of this char (`|`) outputs and give it to the command on the right side as input. And `Hello, it is good sunny Day` is no command but the output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a pipe in `subprocess`, you can't just pass it as an argument in the list. Instead, you should pass the whole command as a string with `shell=True`. Something like this:

```
import subprocess

txt = "Hello, it is good sunny Day"
res = subprocess.Popen(["echo", txt], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res1 = subprocess.Popen("grep good", stdin=res.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res.stdout.close()  

output = res1.communicate()[0]
print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems it is not working. I have read the documentation, but no result. I know that I should start with a command and the output should be piped to other commands, but I cant pass the first command , so the result of it to be forward it.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    res1 = subprocess.Popen("grep good", stdin=res.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1950, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'grep good'